# Arranging Data according to their page number in reports

Tags: mysql, sql

I got this problem regarding the pages the data is supposed to be placed.
This is how they look on the database.

```
CODE PAGE  
---- ----  
A    1  
A    2  
A    1  
B    2   
B    2  
C    3   
C    3  
C    4  
D    4  
D    4   
D    4  
D    3
```

My desired output is

```
CODE PAGE  
---- ----  
A    1  
A    1  
A    1  
B    2  
B    2  
C    3  
C    3  
C    3  
D    4  
D    4   
D    4  
D    4
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Ok i have to explain it much thoroughly then, if you look at the group of data letter "A" there are 3 of them but the 2nd one it's page is number 2. I want to change it so that it will be in page 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works in SQL SERVER

```
select Code,Dense_Rank() Over (order by [Code]) Page from TableName
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c4939/2)

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
select CODE,PAGE from <myTABLE>
order by PAGE,CODE
```

Comment: all "a" must be 1 cause 1 coresponds to their page number and so as "c" which must be all 3 and "d" must all be 4. I want to use a query cause i have over 600 of these kinds of data.